# Event Handlers don't fire in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, safari

I'm experiencing a problem that occurs only in the Safari browser. My website is built upon Bootstrap 3, therefore I use jQuery.

The code is very simple, for instance:

```
if($('#cadastro')){        //check if there is 'cadastro' page
    $('.btn-plan-select').click(function(){        //if so, add click event to some buttons
        $('.btn-plan-selected').removeClass('btn-plan-selected');
        $(this).addClass('btn-plan-selected');    
        plan = $(this).attr('id');
        $('input#plano').val(plan);        //add some value to a hidden input
    });
}
```

The expected behaviour is that the clicked button gets colored and the previous selected button gets uncolored. In Safari nothing happens.

I've tried to wrap all my `<body>` content with a `<div onClick="">` as I've saw in some topics here, but nothing changed.

[Here are the page](http://comcienciaconsultoria.com.br/quero-ser-saudavel) that has those buttons cited above.

Comment: `if($('#cadastro')){` FYI, that condition will always be `true`.

Comment: Buttons get colored in safari, for me.

Comment: @pvg I've tested in Safari version 10.0.2, what is your version?

Comment: Desktop Safari 10.1. You can try the Safari Technology Preview to see if it's a version thing.